# Calculate rank of the users based on their max score using mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, dense-rank

I have a table (called users) I need rank of users based on their score but I want rank on the bases of users max score.

```
+-----------+------------+
| User_id   | Score      |
+-----------+------------+
| 1         | 12258      | 
| 1         | 112        |
| 2         | 9678       |
| 5         | 9678       |
| 3         | 689206     |
| 3         | 1868       |
```

Expect result

```
+-----------+------------+---------+
| User_id   | Score      | Rank    |
+-----------+------------+---------+
| 3         | 689206     |   1     |     
| 1         | 12258      |   2     |
| 2         | 9678       |   3     |
| 5         | 9678       |   3     |
```

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: I updated my question with Expect result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for `DENSE_RANK`, But it supports mysql version higher than 8.0

1. use correlated-subquery to get `max` value by each `User_id`
2. use two variables one to store `rank` another to store previous value to make the `DENSE_RANK` number.

look like this.

```
CREATE TABLE T(
   User_id int,
   Score int
); 

insert into t values (1,12258); 
insert into t values (1,112);
insert into t values (2,9678);
insert into t values (5,9678);
insert into t values (3,689206);
insert into t values (3,1868);
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT User_id,Score,Rank
FROM (
  SELECT User_id,
         Score,
         @rank :=IF(@previous = t1.score, @rank, @rank + 1) Rank,
         @previous := t1.Score
  FROM T t1 CROSS JOIN (SELECT @Rank := 0,@previous := 0) r
  WHERE t1.Score = 
  (
    SELECT  MAX(Score)  
    FROM T tt
    WHERE t1.User_id = tt.User_id
  ) 
  ORDER BY Score desc
) t1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/15635b/15/0)**:

```
| User_id |  Score | Rank |
|---------|--------|------|
|       3 | 689206 |    1 |
|       1 |  12258 |    2 |
|       2 |   9678 |    3 |
|       5 |   9678 |    3 |
```

Comment: Please View my Expect result

Answer (score 2):

Another trick in MySql 5.7 to calculate a [DENSE_RANK](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_dense-rank) (like in MySql 8) is to use a CASE WHEN with the variable assignments in it.

```
SELECT User_id, MaxScore AS Score,
  CASE 
  WHEN MaxScore = @prevScore THEN @rnk
  WHEN @prevScore := MaxScore THEN @rnk := @rnk+1 
  ELSE @rnk := @rnk+1
  END AS Rank
FROM 
(
  SELECT User_id, MAX(Score) AS MaxScore
  FROM YourTable
  GROUP BY User_id
  ORDER BY MaxScore DESC, User_id
) AS q
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @rnk := 0, @prevScore := null) AS vars
```

You can test it [here](https://rextester.com/BXF95853) on rextester.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  MySQL does not guarantee the order of evaluation of expressions in a `SELECT`, so a variable should not be assigned in one expression and referenced in another.

Comment: But about those that have score 0 ?

Comment: @NorbertBoros Well spotted. A 0 is false in MySql, so the second `WHEN` didn't add 1. F.e. `select case when 0 then true else false end`  returns 0.  Adding an `ELSE` fixed it.